# CakePHP 2.0 default page has no layout and shows mod_rewrite error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I just configured cakePHP 2.0 on my server but the default page has no layout and css applied. It also displays the following error.

> URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. 1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting

I already found out that the no-layout/css issue is probably related to the URL Rewriting error so I followed the steps described at [this Cookbook page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess) but it does not have any effect. The URL rewrite error is still visible and the default page still misses its layout and css styles.

**Some info**

- Display errors in php.ini is on
- The css and favicon.ico included in the html head give an 404
- Both files are in webroot folder
- Location of webroot folder is /admin/app/webroot/
- phpinfo() says mod_rewrite module is loaded
- *Folder structure is as follows:*

  - html (apache root folder)

    - admin

      - app

        - ...
        - webroot

          - css

            - cake.generic.css
        - ...
      - cake
      - lib
      - ...

**The error log only shows**

```
[error] [client 212.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin/css, referer: http://***.nl/admin/
[error] [client 212.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin/img, referer: http://***.nl/admin/ 
[error] [client 212.***.***.***] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin/favicon.ico
```

**Contents of /admin/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /admin/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Contents of /admin/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /admin/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is mod_rewrite activated on your server?

Comment: I assumed it is because the following line was in my httpd.conf 
_LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so_ and I did not put it there myself. But maybe it is not, how can I check?

Comment: If you add a simple phpinfo(), in the Apache configuration section you should find a list of all modules loaded. mod_rewrite should be there.

Comment: You've not mentioned `.htaccess`, you've done that right?

Comment: Yes it came with the cakePHP files and I already checked if they where the same as in the cookbook article I mentioned in my opening post.

Comment: By no layout, you mean no HTML? Is the cake.generic.css file properly loaded? The div of the mod_rewrite message is hidden by the default CSS if the module is properly loaded, but if the CSS is not included you might see it anyway. I've had this problem on 1.3 installations, so I'm not sure if it applies to 2.0.

Comment: @mensch you are right. When I follow the stylesheet link it gives me an 404 error as well as the favicon.ico link. 

Do you remember the cause? I can't try out things now because I'm at work but you helped me a lot already.

Comment: Good to hear! :) I've posted my next reply as an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally posted this as a comment, but as this seems to be of relevance to the OP I'll make it an official answer. The stylesheet link gives a 404 error.

By no layout, you mean no HTML? Is the cake.generic.css file properly loaded? The div of the mod_rewrite message is hidden by the default CSS if the module is properly loaded, but if the CSS is not included you might see it anyway.

I've had this problem on 1.3 installations, so I'm not sure if it applies to 2.0.

As for the 404 error, it might be a superfluous question: but is the favicon.ico actually present in the `webroot` directory and the `cake.generic.css` in `/webroot/css/`?

Also, are you running the application in a subdirectory, or is the `app` directory in the HTTP root of the webserver?

If you are running the application in a subdirectory you might want to change the RewriteBase in both the `.htaccess` of the `app` directory (or whatever it's called) where your models, controllers, etc. are stored and the `webroot` directory.

The .htaccess for the `/app` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /YOUR_APP_DIR/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

And `/app/webroot`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /YOUR_APP_DIR/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Change YOUR_APP_DIR to the relevant path on you webserver. [Here's more](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess) on specific installations of Cake, it might be applicable to your setup.

**EDIT:**
The .htaccess doesn't look right. I think it should be: `/admin/app/` in both files.

If that doesn't work you could investigate the way the CSS is called in `default.ctp`. The call to the CSS is formatted like so in `default.ctp`: 
`<?php echo $this->Html->css(array("/css/cake.generic"), "stylesheet", array("media"=>"screen")); ?>`

You could also override the stock `default.ctp` by placing a file with that name in `/View/Layouts`, the Cookbook example can be found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1080/Layouts). When that is done you can experiment with the full path to the css file and see if the server is correctly serving it.

Comment: My cakePHP indeed was in a subdirectory. It's called 'admin' and I added the RewriteBase rule to the .htaccess files in app, webroot and cake main folder. Still it gives me an 404 on the cake.generic.css file. I already checked if the mod_rewrite module is loaded (through phpinfo() ) and it is.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the cake main directory. Could you update your question with the folder structure on your web server? Also, what's the path to cake.generic.css file and can you verify that the particular path exists in the webroot directory?

Comment: Also, the strange thing is you should get a lot of errors regarding all this, is debugging set to 2 in Config/core.php? You might want to turn on PHP errors temporarily as well by setting php_flag display_errors "1" in the root .htaccess file.

Comment: - Display errors setting in php.ini is on
- Display errors php flag in .htaccess is on
- Debug in cakephp set to 2
- There are no errors
- Webroot folder is in '/admin/app/webroot/'
- Webroot folder contains both cake.generic.css and favicon.ico

Comment: My error log does show errors. 

`[error] [client 212.******] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin/css, referer: http://******.nl/admin/

[error] [client 212.******] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin/img, referer: http://******.nl/admin/

[error] [client 212.******] File does not exist: /var/www/html/admin/favicon.ico`

Comment: In your edited question you state that cake.generic.css is in the webroot directory. It should be in the css directory of the webroot. Also the error log refers to files supposed to be in /var/www/html/, yet your server setup had public_html somewhere in its path (probably /var/www/public_html/). Could you post the contents of your current .htaccess, both in the webroot and admin directory?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was tired yesterday and made some mistakes in my post. I updated the OP now.

Comment: I got crazy so I decided to completely remove apache from my server and reinstall it. Now it does work without me changing anything to any cake files, so it must have been some very well hidden problem with apache and htaccess. It's fixed now and I want to thank @mensch very much for your help!